# How do I send message from localhost to React frontend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, websocket, axios

I have a WebSocket server that is receiving streams of messages from an MQTT source and the message is sent to a localhost server (port 8080). The message received is a stream of random numbers.

Python code for the Websocket server:

```
# Acts as localhost server
import websockets
import asyncio
import requests
import json

PORT = 3001

print("Server listening on Port " + str(PORT))

async def echo(websocket, path):
    print("A client just connected")
    try:
        async for message in websocket:
            hello ="test"
            text = message
            print("Received message from client: " + message)
            payload = {'value':message}
            r = requests.post('http://localhost:8080', params=payload)
            print(r)
            await websocket.send("Pong: " + text + message + hello)
    except websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosed as e:
        print("A client just disconnected")

start_server = websockets.serve(echo, "localhost", PORT)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

Example of message stream as printed out from log:

```
A client just connected
Received message from client: 35
<Response [200]>
A client just connected
Received message from client: 38
<Response [200]>
A client just connected
Received message from client: 38
<Response [200]>
A client just connected
Received message from client: 38
<Response [200]>
A client just connected
Received message from client: 33
<Response [200]>
```

Then, I attempt to read the numbers from 'http://localhost:8080' from my React frontend app using a GET request using Express and Axios However it didn't work and probably because I am not very experienced with the JS API packages. As such, how do I read the messages from my React app?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this using `npm i socket.io-client`

```
const socket = io("http://localhost:8080"); // connects to server address


socket.on('connect', () => {
  console.log('connected to server');
});

socket.emit("Pong: ", "hello") // this is to send

/* this is to listen */
socket.on("value-to-listen-too", (params) => {
    ...
}
```

In your react app I would put the socket on a context. Then pass it whereever its needed. Then in the file where I would use socket I would use an effect hook like so

```
 useEffect(() => {

    socket.on("read-message", (message) => {
      someFunc(message)
    })

    return () => {
      // turn off sockets after exiting app / page
      socket.off("read-message")
    };
  }, [socket]);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. So the socket would listen to my python WebSocket server? If so, how do i take the data as shown in the log? Sorry i'm really new to this

Comment: The socket listens to your python webserver. I already showed how to send (`.emit`) and receive data (`.on`) in my answer.